# Reattach laptop keyboard button

Tags: keyboard-layout

See this picture, one of these **little plastics** broken.

I can't attach my button back to my laptop

Please help me what can I do .

[image]

Comment: If the tabs are broken, the key will not clip back on, so you need to replace the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your image, the key itself is broken.

Find a company that can sell you a keycap replacement for your keyboard
model and buy the broken keycap. Usually this is pretty cheap.

The company will also supply you the instructions on how to install the new keycap,
but here are some resources which might help:

- [Laptop Key Installation Guide](https://www.replacementlaptopkeys.com/laptop-key-installation-guide/)
- [Definitive Guide To Fixing a Broken Keyboard Key and Mistakes To Avoid](https://www.replacementlaptopkeys.com/definitive-guide-to-fixing-a-broken-keyboard-key-and-mistakes-to-avoid/)
- [How do I fix a broken laptop key or put it back on?](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001245.htm)

You will likely also find videos for your keyboard on YouTube.